# Remote 3D-accelerated OpenGL apps from Windows server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, opengl

Is there any solution that will you allow you to run GPU-accelerated OpenGL applications remotely, given:

- The remote machine is a Microsoft Windows server
- There is a 3D graphics card in the remote machine (e.g., NVIDIA, ATI)

In particular, is this possible over RDP using the Microsoft Remote desktop Client?

As far as I can tell Microsoft's RemoteFX technology only does 3D acceleration for DirectX, it doesn't 3D accelerate OpenGL. VirtualGL+VNC works for Linux, but there isn't a Windows port as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thinanywhere](http://www.thinanywhere.com/pro3drdp.php4) has an RDP plugin that they claim can use the GPU to accelerate OpenGL on the server.

In addition, Citrix recently released an [add-on](http://blogs.citrix.com/2013/03/19/opengl-gpu-sharing-on-xenapp-introduces-gpu-acceleration-of-virtualized-3d-graphics-apps-to-millions-more-3d-users/) to XenApp 6.5 that does allow GPU sharing for OpenGL. They have supported Direct3D GPU sharing for a while (with the proper regkey set) on XenApp as well.

Answer (score 4):

[Citrix XenDesktop](http://www.citrix.com/products/xendesktop/features/high-def-experience/hdx-3d-pro.html) supports GPU-accelerated OpenGL via the Citrix Receiver (universal thin client application) for Linux, OS X, Android and Windows and would support your use-case on the operating systems you mentioned.

The Microsoft equivalent, [RemoteFX](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16652.remotefx-vgpu-setup-and-configuration-guide-for-windows-server-2012.aspx) (on RDP), while it does support GPUs and OpenGL 1.1, is more limited on the operating systems supported.  Unsure if you can use any standard Linux RDP client with it.

Comment: You could do a couple things with XenDesktop. You could assign a physical desktop with the GPU to a user and they would have direct access to the GPU that way and, with the HDX license, would be able to do full DirectX/OpenGL. You could also add a hypervisor with GPU passthrough to assign the GPU to a virtual desktop. Again, have access to the GPU. Both of these solutions are limited to having only one user having access to the GPU at a time (unless you had multiple GPU's in the remote system).

Comment: I tried RemoteFX on RDP, but I could not confirm that it was actually accelerating the OpenGL 1.1. Subjectively, I couldn't tell a difference in performance, and querying OpenGL to get rendering info gave the same response as when not using RemoteFX.